# calculation sum of a django model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Transaction:
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

Now I calculate the sum of amount

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
amount = 0
for transaction in transactions:
    balance = transaction.amount
    amount += balance
```

I know it is calculate by using agreegate. But is this possible by this way or another way ?

Answer (score 3):

```
ModelName.objects.aggregate(Sum('field_name'))
```

Here is the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum)

Comment: I want to calculate sum into the loop

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Is that possible ?

Comment: Yeah, the way you do it would work. But it's slower, and it doesn't seem to have any benefits to Dan's solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why not use aggregate, if you wanna iterate you can try

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.values_list('amount', flat=True)
amount = sum(list(transactions))
```